# What's wrong with this Ajax code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this Ajax code and I can't figure it out what's wrong with it

```
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://url.to.json",
         async: false,
         beforeSend: function(x) {
          if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) {
           x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
          }
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
    alert(data.meta.poster);
}});
```

Comment: don't share your original url :). try to share test url if needed.

Comment: don't use `async:false` ... it is a terrible practice and browsers are already logging deprecation notices in console when you use it. There is just no need to use it in the first place

Comment: what is this: `if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) {`? I guess it should be `x &&`

Comment: Hi @charlietfl i've removed the `async:false` and that doesn't seems to be the problem

Comment: that won't cause it to not work...url provided returns a 403 status though. Inspect the actual request in dev tools of browser console. Are you sending proper authentication?

Answer (score 1):

just remove '-' from `"application/j-son;charset=UTF-8"`

like this

> application/json; charset=utf-8

try this. its working perfect for me.

```
    $.getJSON("http:// paste your url", function(reponse){
            alert(JSON.stringify(reponse))
   });
```

Comment: I had edit my answer, and its working perfect now. Try yourself.

Comment: can you make on jsfiddle? What version of jquery i need?

Comment: its working perfect when I had open your url's website ("http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/") and then run the above script on console. But when I copied the same script on jsfiddle I got error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" :). you have to solve this error.